# Include API key in web request header

Tags: authentication, webrequest, api-key

I am trying to use a simple API in a WindowsForms application I am developing in VB.NET using Visual Studio. The API's endpoint is at https://netservice-prod.apigee.net/upc/a2a/api/v7/languages
. The [documentation of the API](https://www.unified-patent-court.org/sites/default/files/upc_documents/opt-out_apis_instructions_v2.2.1.pdf) says:

> All API requests must be authenticated by the use of a Developer App Key. This key is secret to the developer and must be added to each request’s header section identified by name “X-API-KEY”. [...]

> The API to retrieve the list of permitted languages does not need any parameter other than the “X-API-KEY”, which must be specified in the header of the request.

I have a key which I believe to be valid.

I am trying to do this (i.e. get the response from the API) as follows:

```
Const URL_LANG = "https://netservice-prod.apigee.net/upc/a2a/api/v7/languages"
Const KEY = "MyKey"  ' Obviously, I put the actual value in my real code

Dim result As String
Dim request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL_LANG)
request.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", KEY)
request.Method = "GET"
result = New System.IO.StreamReader(request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream).ReadToEnd
```

I have also tried this:

```
With New Net.WebClient
   .Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", KEY)
   result = .DownloadString(URL_LANG)
End With
```

But I cannot get this to work. Rather, I keep getting the error message "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."

I have found a few posts here relating to similar problems, but I do not understand the answers and cannot get the proposed solutions to work. (I do not really understand the details of web requests etc.) Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem. (This should be so esay.) Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still comes to this: There was nothing wrong with my code as such. It was a security protocol issue. The problem was solved by adding the following line (e.g. in the handler of the Shown event of the main form of my application)

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

The further code then looks something like this:

```
Private Shared CLIENT As New HttpClient
CLIENT.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-API-KEY", My.Settings.APIKey)
result = Await CLIENT.GetStringAsync(URL_LANG)
```